# Safari border-color hover bug

Tags: css, colors, safari, hover

So I'm currently facing an issue when you hover over an element in Safari (Version 6.0.2) the border color on that element seems to act a little weird. To give you a break down of what I've done the element is just a simple list element which has the same border color on all sides except the left hand side.

Heres an example:
http://cl.ly/MPkG

Upon hover I add a simple CSS3 Scale transition to the element as well as changing the border color to a darker shade of grey (excluding the left hand side).

Here is a real rough fiddle to show the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/dannykeane/N4jF5/

This works perfectly fine in all modern browsers except Safari (Version 6.0.2). I've also tried adding a `backface-visibility:hidden;` to this element but it still behaves the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: good effort on the video but i couldnt watch it. anyway consider using jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com instead of videos and screenshots.

Comment: Heres a real quick mock up of what I've done if you test it in safari you'll see the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/dannykeane/N4jF5/

Comment: it gets blurry on hover (testing on chrome). What is it doing wrong?

Comment: http://cl.ly/MPQS This is what happens in Safari

Comment: It happens in the fiddle too http://cl.ly/MPon

Comment: I'm getting a weird patch of yellow on the bottom and top borders. Looks like a bug in Safari to me.

Answer (score 1):

That *may be* an unknown bug in Safari, though the bug quite makes sense because you are trying to put a **thicker border on the left** than the rest of the sides of the box. The bleeding is visible with a `border-radius` defined. If you have equal thickness on all sides, even there is border radius, there wouldn't be any overflowing border.

You may also notice if you adjust the border thickness on the left, the bleeding wouldn't be visible, unless you zoom in/out the page. Perhaps adjusting the values wouldn't help either, as this would be unstable and a temporary solution.

We couldn't do anything with the browser specific bug, but a workaround. We could separate the thicker border to the next div surrounding your content inside. And don't forget to remove the 1px border left on the parent div:

```
border-left: 0;
```

Like this basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgYhQ/